# Java Web Service Client class call from Oracle DB server

Tags: java, oracle, static

I am using a java web service client class, in order to call this class from Oracle database should I make the accessible method in the class static?

Comment: Please rewrite your question in a way that everyone can understand it

Comment: I am using a java class as web service client, my question is the method inside the class for calling the service is that should be static

Comment: You mean the method that will consume the WS? Well, it would depend on your design, but I guess it won't be a problem.

Comment: I created the class in NetBeans and tried to upload it to Oracle database to be called from trigger, the loadjava was successful but on executing the method via oracle procedure the error message was showing that the method is not found until I changed the method to static, it was identified but it was showing the error message:javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Your_Class_Source" as 
public class Your_Class {
   public static void Your_Java_Func() {

   }
};

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Your_PLSQL_Procedure
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Your_Class.Your_Java_Func()';
```

Comment: many thanks, so you mean I should resolve the java class in Oracle and there will be no need to declare the method as static in java class

Comment: @user2079954 - Your method MUST be static.

Comment: great, but making the method static throws the error message javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl not found

Comment: @user2079954 are you implementing an Oracle procedure using Java?

Comment: yes, so that I can call the web service client based on oracle table event trigger

Comment: @user2079954 next time **you should post all the relevant info on your question**, we can't just guess what technology you're working with or trying to make it work if you don't tell us.

Comment: @user2079954 - All classes used by your class should also be loaded to Oracle DB, if they are not present in JDK 1.6.

Comment: Yes I uploaded all the required class and I understand Oracle 11g database embedded JVM supports JRE 1.5.